# how to set listview with multiple fonts

Tags: android

My application have listview with friends name in Marathi and Hindi fonts.
But names in Marathi and Hindi fonts are displayed as block.

I also have `.ttf` file for Marathi and Hindi fonts and i also added that in `assets->fonts` folder.

Comment: if your font displayed as a block then may be problem in your .ttf file..

Comment: though you have added fonts for hindi and marathi, but your sdk's font renderer engine does not know how to draw devanagri script.

Comment: different font for same row's text or different font for different rows???

Comment: @Awais Tariq : different font for different row.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this ::**

here i have set comic font in my textview. you can copy file in assets folder and apply following code :

```
Typeface face;
face = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/comic.TTF");
tran_banner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tran_banner);
            tran_banner.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD);
```